# Why custom List view button sends only 20 records to visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce, list-view, list-button, lightninglistview

I am performing some bulk operation on the Account list view. For this purpose, I used the custom List button **Say Hello** of `visualforce` type with the following attributes:-

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" recordSetVar="ids" tabStyle="Account">
```

The strange thing is I am able to select up to 200 records on list view but when I click to **Say Hello** button it only passes 20 records on the visualforce page. Please let me know how can I pass all records to VF page. Also, let me know if it is a limitation from salesforce.

Thanks.

Comment: It would be worth while to also provide your Apex behind the bulk operation.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_sosc_pagination.htm), 20 is the default.  If you want to display more records, you'll have to write a controller extension class.

> By default, a list controller returns 20 records on the page. To
>   control the number of records displayed on each page, use a controller
>   extension to set the pageSize. For information on controller
>   extensions, see Building a Controller Extension.